# Ggplot title background color/fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to get a background color (like strip.background) to a title (sub/caption) element in ggplot2?

Comment: There may have been new functionality added in the last few years, but if not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351011/customize-background-color-of-ggtitle is relevant

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you're really in a pickle, you can try creating your title elements using `geom_label()`, whose argument "fill" controls the background color. You would need to plot outside the panel region though, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot.