# ggplot2 line between title and subtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to include a line, like a separator, between the title and the subtitle with ggPlot? I know how to color the background of the title (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351011/customize-background-color-of-ggtitle) Post)

Comment: Not terrific but you can do: `ggtitle("My title\n_______________________________________________", "My subtitle")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to manually trace a segment using `geom_segment` while setting `clip = "off"` on `coord_cartesian`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 2:11)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Main Title", subtitle = "Subtitle")+
  coord_cartesian(clip ="off")+
  geom_segment(x =0.5, xend = 2.5, y = 12.1, yend = 12.1)
```

[image]

You will have to adapt the position based on data you are going to plot but it is one possible solution

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Works really well for single Plots. Am I correct in assuming there is no such solution to include this divider in a theme?

Comment: You're welcome ;) For your question, to my knowledge, I don't think so (but maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Another option simply to underline your Main title

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 2:11)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = ~ underline("Main Title"), subtitle = "Subtitle")
```

related thread: [How to underline text in a plot title or label? (ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470293/how-to-underline-text-in-a-plot-title-or-label-ggplot2)

You could also play around in order to achieve a solution as suggested by user Stephane Laurent in their comment, pasting some empty spaces after a line break

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to encorporate these solutions in a dynamic way. Any how, maybe something along these lines is possible in a future update of ggPlot